# Program that removes extra spaces from input and displays correctly spaced output

Tags: c#

Write a program that removes all double spaces in the string. It should read a string from the console and store it in the variable input. You should declare input using var. Pay attention only to double spaces, we are not focusing on triple and more spaces in this task.
For example, if the input is `I love  computer  science`

the output should be
    `I love computer science`.

this is what i have so far:

```
using System;

namespace LearningVar
{
    class DoubleSpaces
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i){
                if (input[i] != ' ')
                Console.Write(input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i can't get the words to space correctly. please and thank you!

Comment: `Pay attention only to double spaces` There is a triple space after love. Why was it changed to a single space?

Comment: Can you talk us through why `input = input.Replace("  ", " ");` (the first parameter being two spaces, the second being one) won't work?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use regex?

```
string spaces = "i do    not ";
string singleSpace = Regex.Replace(spaces.Trim(), @"\s+", " ");
Debug.WriteLine(singleSpace);
```

Or

```
singleSpace = string.Join(" ", spaces.Split(new char[] {' '}), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or

```
while (spaces.Contains("  "))
    spaces = spaces.Replace("  ", " ");
```

Comment: The OP said "Pay attention only to double spaces, we are not focusing on triple and more spaces in this task" - all of your solutions will reduce triple spaces too as far as I can see...

Comment: @Chris I know.  OP is conflicted.